# Missing HSTS Header (1) Flaw in ASP.Net application

Tags: asp.net, hsts

We have a ASP.Net application and the following vulnerability is reported in it.
**The web-application does not define an HSTS header, leaving it vulnerable to attack.**

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: What research have you done to solve this problem?  Did you see [the first link on Google](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security)?